# android-studio no exporta APK

Tags: android-studio

Al usar android studio por primera vez no exporta el apk [image: app-debug no ejecuta en dispositivos, cuando lo exporto otra vez nada cambia nisiquiera aparece otra copia. Seria un problema en la instalación? ya que en el api que uso del android studio, todos los botones aparecen uno encima de otro]

Comment: ¿Acaso elegiste la opción  `Build` del menú principal y dentro de ella elegiste `Build Bundled(s) / APK(s)`? Si no haces eso no se va a crear ninguna APK. Parece que ahora mismo lo único que haces es Debug.

Answer (score 0):

El .APK creado dentro de `app\build\outputs\apk\debug` se genera al construir tu aplicación, también cuando realizas `Build` > `Make Project`,  `Build` > `Rebuild Project` o cuando subes la aplicación a tu dispositivo móvil.

Cuando realizas `Clean` > `Build Project` se elimina.

Si el archivo .apk no se genera dentro de  `app\build\outputs\apk\debug`, indica que no se está compilando tu proyecto, es importante que revises que sucede en tu proyecto, ya que tiene errores.